# Merging 2 entity graphs in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Does EF have support for something like this? Let's pretend I have 3 entities

```
Customer
Orders
OrderLines
```

`Orders` is a childs of `Customer` and `OrderLines` is a child of `Order`

Once I load this structure using EF - I return it to Web API client (disconnected).

When client returns graph (POSTs back to server) - I know only one fact: this is the same `Customer` but I want to merge Orders/Lines to the database.

Probably not perfect example with Orders, but this is what we need. We want to support standard "REST" type logic on client and not make client track entities.

So, I want (when data is POSTed back) to load same graph from server and take this disconnected graph and apply to loaded one.

Basically walking properties one by one on `Customer`, then seeing which Orders got deleted, which got Added and update properties on those Updated.

Is there a built-in generic way to update property values from one entity to another?

Or maybe there is ready to go pattern/tutorial for doing exactly this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noone responded but I found a solution, maybe going to help someone:
http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/graphdiff-aggregate-mappings/

There is extension for DbContext which will allow for 2 entity graph merging. Exactly what we were looking for.